# My compound text does not refresh over my Tkinter image

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

This is my first time using Tkinter and Python. I want to run a series of 4 images in a loop. The user interacts with the interface by clicking each image. My 4th image has a compound text which appears on it. I am unable to make this compound text disappear for when the program starts again.

This is the line of code with initiates the compound text :

```
displayButton.configure(image=photo4, text = sc , compound=CENTER, fg = 'Black',      font='Verdana 30 bold', command=callback, wraplength=250, justify=CENTER)

currentpicture=4
```

This is the code which configures the displayButton, but it does not work.

```
if currentpicture==4:
displayButton.configure(image=photo1) 
currentpicture=1
```

can anybody please help ?

This is the complete code :

```
import sys
import cwiid
import time
import math
import numpy
from Tkinter import*


# declares the variable currentpicture to be 1
currentpicture = 1

lt = [None]*100
lb = [None]*100
rt = [None]*100
rb = [None]*100 

right_top_cal = 0
left_top_cal = 0
right_bottom_cal = 0
left_bottom_cal = 0

right_top = 0
left_top = 0
right_bottom = 0
left_bottom = 0

# defines the function for the callback button
# declares the screen and currentpicture as global variables
# checks the current picture and change it :) 

def callback():
  global currentpicture
  global roundedresult
  global displayButton
  global sock
  global wiimote
  global comment 

  if currentpicture==4:
    displayButton.configure(image=photo1) 
    currentpicture=1
  if currentpicture==3:
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    # Probably a good idea to have recently calibrated your Balance Board on your Wii
    balance_calibration = wiimote.get_balance_cal()
    # print balance_calibration
    right_top_cal = balance_calibration[0][0]
    right_bottom_cal = balance_calibration[1][0]
    left_top_cal = balance_calibration[2][0]
    left_bottom_cal = balance_calibration[3][0]

    print 'Calibration complete'

    while (count <= 100):
        # Quite a slow refresh rate. Feel free to reduce this time (it's in seconds)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        wiimote.request_status()

        right_top = wiimote.state['balance']['right_top'] - right_top_cal
        right_bottom =  wiimote.state['balance']['right_bottom'] - right_bottom_cal
        left_top =  wiimote.state['balance']['left_top'] - left_top_cal
        left_bottom = wiimote.state['balance']['left_bottom'] - left_bottom_cal

        count2 += 1
        if (count2 < 10):
            print 'wait'

        elif (count2 >= 10):
            if (count < 100):
                lt[count] = left_top
                lb[count] = left_bottom
                rt[count] = right_top
                rb[count] = right_bottom
                count += 1
                print left_top
            elif (count == 100):
                result = ( numpy.std(lt, axis=0) + numpy.std(lb, axis=0) + numpy.std(rb,  axis=0) + numpy.std(rb, axis=0) )
                print ('%.2f'%result)
                roundedresult = ('%.2f'%result)
                score = (1000 - float(roundedresult))
                score2 = int(score)/90
                score2 = ('%.2f'%score)
                if score2 <=3:
                    comment = 'Thanks for trying, have another go'
                elif score2 <=6:
                    comment = 'Not bad but room for improvement'
                elif score2 <=9:
                    comment  = 'Your Balance is great'
                elif score2>9:
                    comment = 'Balance Master'
                sc= score2,comment
                count += 1
    displayButton.configure(image=photo4, text = sc , compound=CENTER, fg = 'Black', font='Verdana 30 bold', command=callback, wraplength=250, justify=CENTER)
     currentpicture=4

  if currentpicture==2:

     # Wii Balance Board
    rpt_mode = 0

    # Change the number below to the Bluetooth MAC address of your Wii Balance Board
    # You get that by pressing red sync button in battery compartment and then running
    # hcitool scan  
    wiimote = cwiid.Wiimote("00:22:4C:42:06:C0")

    rpt_mode ^= cwiid.RPT_EXT

    wiimote.rpt_mode = rpt_mode

    print 'Pairing complete'
    displayButton.configure(image=photo3)
    currentpicture=3


  if currentpicture==1:
    roundedresult = None
    displayButton.configure(image=photo2, text=roundedresult, compound =CENTER)
    currentpicture=2

root = Tk()
photo1=PhotoImage(file='1.gif')
photo2=PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
photo3=PhotoImage(file='3.gif')
photo4=PhotoImage(file='4.gif')
displayButton=Button(None, text=None)
displayButton.pack()

 # gives a size to the screen and places it in the center
 # gives a title to the screen

root.geometry('320x240+0+0')
root.title('BALANCE BOARD')

## removes decoration from the window 
root.overrideredirect(1)
displayButton['image']=photo1
displayButton['command']=callback
displayButton.pack

#puts an image of height 240 into the label and packs it into an appropriate size 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is incorrect. Can you fix it, please?

Comment: When you say "This is the code which configures the displayButton, but it does not work.", what does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Dear Bryan, I have just fixed the indentation. When I say it does not work I mean that, when I press the button:  the 4th image is changed to 1st image, but the text generated from screen 4 continues to display on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add text to a button, it will stay there until you change it. Try this:

```
displayButton.configure(image=photo1, text='')
```